# 'inlining' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, optimization

In JavaScript, with my own emulator implementation, getting the value of register field `RA` from a 32-bit instruction `i` is often represented as:

```
this.gpr.u32[(i >> 16) & 0x1f]
```

However, having the above expression many times in a function is ugly and hard to follow and edit. I have avoided defining a variable `ra` with that expression and using it because I thought that it would be stored in memory, and fetching it would be costly. Should I be worried about this or do modern JavaScript engines 'inline' the value of the variable into the statements that follow the definition? Though using a variable makes the code much cleaner, I don't really want to use it if it will slow down the execution time in a performance-sensitive environment such as an emulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of "it depends" in an answer. First of all it depends on the javascript interpreter how good it can optimize.

Nevertheless, if I understand you correctly your code is something like

```
.... this.gpr.u32[(i >> 16) & 0x1f] ...
.... this.gpr.u32[(i >> 16) & 0x1f] ...
.... this.gpr.u32[(i >> 16) & 0x1f] ...
```

instead of

```
ra = this.gpr.u32[(i >> 16) & 0x1f];
.... ra ....
.... ra ....
.... ra ....
```

In this case I suppose any javascript engine will execute the latter much faster. It is true that you have an additional variable `ra` in memory. But access to `ra` should not be slower than access to `i` plus shift and mask plus access to `this.gpr.u32`.

Comment: Thanks! So what you're saying is that any unwanted access latency to `ra` would be heavily outdone by the unwanted access latency of fetching `i`, doing a shift, doing an AND, then fetching an item out of `this.gpr.u32`, provided that the long form is not cached somehow automatically by the engine.

Comment: @Delan Azabani: More or less. It is much easier for an engine to inline a single variable than the overall expression and thus I suspect that most engines are much better in the former.